# Power Automate - Export people picker data from a list

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow

We have a sharepoint list that we want to export to excel weekly. However we also want to capture the user information that's in the people picker. See screen shot below. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Power Automate that might help.
For extracting **Business and Mobile Phones** of column type [People], need to use [Get User Profile] action in Power Automate.

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Expressions

```
items('Apply_to_each')?['ID']
items('Apply_to_each')?['Title']
outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body/displayName']
items('Apply_to_each')?['Manager/email']
outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body/businessPhones']
first(outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body/businessPhones'])

Note: ID, Title, Manager are SPO list columns
```

### Detail 2 & 3

[image]